# Each side of a triangle ABC has been extended by its size, giving rise to a new triangle. What is the ratio of the areas of these triangles?

Tags: geometry, area, geometric-construction

In a triangle ABC each side has been extended by it's length, we mark the edges of the segments D,E,F and draw the triangle DEF.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnuqX.png)
What is the ratio of the areas between the two triangles.
Edit: I try to draw it on geogebra and found out it's 1:7 but I have no idea how to prove it.

Comment: Even if it is an equilateral triangle, it is the same question because a ratio of areas is invariant by an affine transformation and it is always possible to transform any triangle into an equilateral triangle by an affine transform.

Comment: See also on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-seventh_area_triangle)